# Nest.JS DTO Validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, nestjs

My DTO is

```
 @Expose()
 @IsNotEmpty()
 @IsJSON({ each: true })
 filesRole: string
```

filesRole is something like that: `[{"file": "14125.png", "role": "bg"}, {"file": "x12.png", "role": "cover"}]`

I want to validate `role` to be `bg` or `cover`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with enum:

```js
export enum Role {
  bg = 'bg',
  cover = 'cover',
}
```

```js
@IsEnum(Role)
@Expose()
@IsNotEmpty()
@IsJSON({ each: true })
filesRole: Role
```

Comment: I want to validate only `role` property. I think the main problem is filesRole is unparsed json.

Answer (score 0):

update your main DTO:

```
@Expose()
@IsNotEmpty()
@IsArray()
@ValidateNested({ each: true })
filesRole: Data[];
```

Data DTO:

```
export class Data {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    file: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    @IsIn(Object.values(roleEnum))
    role: roleEnum;
}
```

roleEnum :

```
export enum roleEnum {
    bg = 'bg',
    cover = 'cover',
}
```

Comment: filesRole is always string because with formdata we can only send a blob(for example file) or a string. We use formdata because sending of files require it.